# Getting Google user's OpenID connect token in Chrome extension script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension that would call a third-party API. The third-party API method validates the Google user using a google_token querystring parameter.

In Apps Script, I can get this token using [ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken). So my code is basically:

```
var token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
var url = "https://my.apiserver.com/mymethod?google_token=" + token;
```

At the backend we validate the token by calling [https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token={token}](https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=%7Btoken%7D).

This works when calling for a REST API client, like Advanced REST Client (ARC).

I'm trying to call the same method in a Chrome extension script. I'm a noob here so please bear with me.

I've been reading up on [documentions/tutorials](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_identity/) and tried the below:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // Use the token.
});
```

This works, I do get a token. But it does not authenticate with the method that works with Apps Script.

Is there something missing at my code?

Are they the same token? If not how do I get the same token as in ScriptApp.getIdentityToken() in Chrome extension?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After further looking into this, I found the correct code. I should have used launchWebAuthFlow method.

Example in [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/identify_user/).

To prevent the UI prompting confirmation from the user, I changed this:

```
authUrl.searchParams.set('prompt', 'consent');
```

to this:

```
authUrl.searchParams.set('prompt', 'none');
```

I hope this helps anyone looking for the same solution.